# Can you do prostituion if you are starving and have no way to support yourself?

Tags: fatwa

As far as i'm aware certain haram things become halal in certain circumstances e.g. if you are dying of hunger and there is no food, you can eat pork or snakes.  If you are dying of hunger with no way to help yourself you can take an interest based loan which is otherwise haram.

In poor countries some muslim women get into prostituion as no one marries them while they have no way to support themselves and their children and they may die of hunger.  since the hunger could lead to death, is it permissable for them to do prostitution as there is no alternative?  If its still haram does it mean it is better to die of starvation with their children?

References or a link to a fatwa on this question would be appreciated.

Comment: On a related topic, إكراه (coercion under threat of being murdered) does not make adultery permissible according to the majority. The case you present is even less compelling as it can be argued that there probably is another means of earning, the prostitute is just unaware or unwilling to explore it.

Comment: First the necessity must be given else this ruling doesn't apply for a potential or hypothetical need. Secondly all statements I found consider zina as the worst evil and therefore excluded it from those "illegal" things one is allowed to do in case of "necessity". As for the case of hunger there are references saying that one can eat haram food, but not by taking it as a (regular) meal one can only eat it if one is about to die (real necessity).